# Complex MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a situation where I need to perform a group by operation based on an array value that sums up occurrences of a field value. The counts are then filtered on and the results are prepared so that they can be displayed according to the condition. Essentially, the documents are transformed back to how they would be presented if you simply used the find function. I am running into an issue of the temporary documents being too large due to the number of items collected in the matchedDocuments array. Any suggestions on how to improve this would be helpful.

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
{
    '$unwind': '$arrayOfValues'
}, {
    '$group': {
        '_id': '$arrayOfValues',
        'x_count': {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [{
                        $eq: ['$field.value', 'x']
                    },
                    1, 0
                ]
            }
        },
        'y_count': {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [{
                        $eq: ['$field.value', 'y']
                    },
                    1, 0
                ]
            }
        },
        'matchedDocuments': {
            '$push': '$$CURRENT'
        }
    }
},
{'$match': {'$or': [{'x_count': {'$gte': 2}}, {'y_count': { '$gte': 1}}]}},
{'$unwind': '$matchedDocuments'},
{
    '$group': {
        '_id': '$matchedDocuments.key',
        'document': {
            '$last': '$$CURRENT.matchedDocuments'
        }
    }
}
], {
    allowDiskUse: true
})
```

Below are some sample documents and the expected result based on the criteria above:

```
// Sample documents

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5407c76b7b1c276c74f90524"), "field" : "x", "arrayOfValues" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5407c76b7b1c276c74f90525"), "field" : "x", "arrayOfValues" : [ "b", "c" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5407c76b7b1c276c74f90526"), "field" : "z", "arrayOfValues" : [ "a" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5407c76b7b1c276c74f90527"), "field" : "x", "arrayOfValues" : [ "a", "c" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5407c76b7b1c276c74f90528"), "field" : "z", "arrayOfValues" : [ "b" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5407c76b7b1c276c74f90529"), "field" : "y", "arrayOfValues" : [ "k" ] }


// Expected Result

[
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5407c76b7b1c276c74f90524"), "field" : "x", "arrayOfValues" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5407c76b7b1c276c74f90525"), "field" : "x", "arrayOfValues" : [ "b", "c" ] }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5407c76b7b1c276c74f90527"), "field" : "x", "arrayOfValues" : [ "a", "c" ] }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5407c76b7b1c276c74f90529"), "field" : "y", "arrayOfValues" : [ "k" ] }
]
```

Comment: The problem is undoubtedly with your first grouping key. But since you a grouping on the values from the array you have just unwound it is difficult to see what you are actually trying to do here. A document sample and expected results usually explain your intent the best.

Comment: I added sample documents and expected results to help visualize the problem.

Comment: Why not just keep a count on the docs of the size of the `arrayOfValues` array? It would make the aggregation a simple find for each value of `field`.

Comment: I don't think that would help solve this problem. You can think of the arrayOfValues as a grouping for each document. I want the results  filtered by the number of occurrences of field with value x (>= 2) or y (>= 1) occurrences within each group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think ultimately you are asking a little too much from a single query, as clearly the biggest problem here is trying to store all of the original documents from whence the array element came whilst trying to aggregate a total.

For me, I would just try to identify which conditions on the document would result in a match and then issue a separate query to get the actual documents back. You could adapt the aggregation below to try to return the document, but I think it's very likely to fail when doing so as it would be the reverse of what you should be using arrays for.

The process is also generally much more efficient in the way it goes about the matching alowing you to firstly "Select the elements you are interested in with a match condition" and secondly, "Use the natural grouping conditions rather than rely on conditional sums".

```js
var cursor = db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "field": { "$in": ["x", "y"] } } },
    { "$unwind": "$arrayOfValues" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
           "elem": "$arrayOfValues",
           "field": "$field"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$match": {
        "$or": [
            { "_id.field": "x", "count": { "$gte": 2 } },
            { "_id.field": "y", "count": { "$gte": 1 } }
         ]
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.field",
        "values": { "$push": "$_id.elem" }
    }}
])

var query = { "$or": [] };

cursor.forEach(function(doc) {
    query["$or"].push({
        "field": doc._id,
        "arrayOfValues": { "$in": doc.values }
    });
});

db.collection.find(query)
```

For the record the query should come out like this, given the supplied data:

```js
{
    "$or" : [
        {
            "field" : "x",
            "arrayOfValues" : {
                "$in" : [
                    "c",
                    "b",
                    "a"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "field" : "y",
            "arrayOfValues" : {
                "$in" : [
                    "k"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The basic logic is met by just looking for the values of "field" that you are interested in, so at least eliminating all others from the possible results. Then you basically want to tally up the counts for each array element under each of those "field" values and test where the required occurrences were met.

This may or may not work best the other way around, but the sample here shows the greatest variation by the "arrayOfValues" so that makes sense as the second level of grouping.

As stated earlier, I think it is too much to ask to basically "stuff" all of the parent document information into an array for each "arrayOfValues" element as this works beyond the basic principles of a sensible schema, where that sort of relation would naturally be stored as separate documents. So the end principle here is just find the "conditions" that match those documents which is what the end result comes out as.

The transformed query is then issued against the collection, where that will return all documents that meet the conditions determined from the previous analysis. At the end of the day, moving the responsibility of "fetching" the matching documents off to another query rather than trying to store the documents that match in arrays.

This seems the most logical and scale-able approach, but if you mostly tend to use your data in this type of result you should be looking at re-designing your schema to suit this better. But there really is not enough specific information here to comment on that further.

Comment: I appreciate the efforts that you have put into your answers. This is similar to what I came up with. However, I was unsure if a better approach was available. There are user defined preconditions that can filter the results further, which reduces the issue of large documents. Additionally, each collection is always going to be less than 5.5 million documents. I tried to abstract away the domain specific things as much as possible to avoid complexity.

Comment: @user1595702 if you are talking about issuing separate queries then there is not a better approach, and I think I explained that. The aggregation framework is powerful, but beware of the "tail wagging the dog". Do things sensibly.